# Woocommerce Short Description display HTML

Tags: html, wordpress, woocommerce, trim, strip

I am trying to find out how to display HTML tags within the short description on a category listing page when using Woocommerce in Wordpress.

The category listing will display a product with the following information:

```
Image
Product Title
Short Description
Price
```

Which may end up being something like

```
Toy Car
This toy car has
the following benefits
it has wheels
it can turn corners fast
it is a nice red colour
```

When in actual fact, because I have enabled the HTML editor for the short description when you view the product the content maybe something like:

```
<h2>Toy Car</h2>
<p>This toy car has the following benefits:</p>
<ul>
<li>it has wheels</li>
<li>it can turn corners fast</li>
<li>it is a nice red colour</li>
</ul>
```

The problem is that something in Woocommerce (or Wordpress) is stripping out the HTML code so I am just left with text.

During my research I have encountered articles which mention 'unfiltered_html', 'wp_strip_all_tags' and 'wp_trim_excerpt' (because apparently the short description is considered to the excerpt.

I was hoping it would be as easy to just a filter to prevent the stripping of HTML and yet despite hours of searching, I haven't found a solution. Plenty of solutions on how to achieve stripping and utilise it but nothing that answers my questions of disabling the strip function and retaining HTML.

Can anyone help? Please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same here. Actually it shows with `<br>` on my product page but when I call it with `$product->get_short_description()` or `$product->post->post_excerpt` it strips html tags.

I managed to find a solution by searching inside woocommerce module files:
`apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $product->get_short_description() );`